# Using a library sibling folder container for shared packages

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

I have many applications in a mono git repository. I'd like to share some libraries between my applications.

Here is is my directory structure:

```
.
├── libs
│   └── messages
|       ├── package.json
|       ├── src
|       ├── tsconfig.json
|       └── ...all other good things for a library
├── main
│   ├── config
│   ├── dist
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── src
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── README.md
└── server
    ├── main.ts
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── setupEnvVars.js
    ├── src
    └── tsconfig.json
```

I want to add the library "message" to my project "main" so I tried to add it this way:

```
{
  "name": "me",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@me/messages": "../libs/messages/"
  }
}
```

I'm stuck because it doesn't work (but doesn't throw errors either). Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd need to see more about the content of each package.json files and the project overall, but here are some elements which may help you get a goo structure that would accomplish what you have set yourself to do.

If you really want to go the proper monorepo way, you might want to have a look at https://github.com/lerna/lerna which will work well enough for Node 8 and up (e.g. auto-symlink of file dependencies, which is useful during development).

Another way to solve this issue in TypeScript is using paths:

> tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // path
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "@lib/*": ["./*"],
        "@shared/*": ["../shared/*"]
    }
}
```

However, depending on how you build and run your projects, paths are sometimes not processed properly. You may need to use `tsconfig-paths` if you run your project using `ts-node`, or `tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin` if you are using TypeScript as part of a webpack project.

Comment: Lerna solved the issue. I'm going to write about because it's still not obvious to me :) .